# How to `Graceful Restart Apache` in centos 7?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

My system is centos 7.4, with apache 2.4
Based on [apache manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html),`apachectl -k graceful` should be the way to graceful restart apache, but I got notice as below:

```
[root@localhost root]# apachectl -k graceful
Passing arguments to httpd using apachectl is no longer supported.
You can only start/stop/restart httpd using this script.
If you want to pass extra arguments to httpd, edit the
/etc/sysconfig/httpd config file.
```

What's the problem?
How to `Graceful Restart Apache` in centos 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please see this page on apachectl, which appears to be a new version:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html

There is no need to pass the '-k' argument. 
`apachectl graceful` 
(without the -k) works just fine for a graceful reload/restart
on my Centos7 box and Centos6 box.

Apparently nobody updated the manual page OP cited in her question, which still exists, and where the commands are shown with the '-k' argument throughout (apachectl -k graceful, apachectl -k restart, etc.) There's no explanation on that page about what the -k argument is actually doing, however.

But on the newer page there is this note on about apachectl graceful:

> This is equivalent to apachectl -k graceful.

On my Centos6 box, I had been using the command `service httpd graceful`.
That no longer worked on Centos7. It's necessary to use `apachectl graceful` to do the equivalent on Centos 7. Also `apachectl graceful` works just fine on Centos 6.

Answer (score 5):

Most systemd-based distributions use a patched `apachectl` script [1] that delegates commands to `systemctl`. The patched `apachectl` command does not support the "pass-through" mode of operation in which arguments are passed through to `httpd`.  The apachectl manual page reflects the upstream non-patched `apachectl` command, hence the discrepancy.

I recommend using the `systemctl` [2] abstraction for starting and stopping services.

Thus, to gracefully restart the Apache HTTP Server on Centos 7, and other linux distributions using systemd, use:

```
sudo systemctl reload httpd.service
```

Under the hood, this invokes `httpd -k graceful`. You can verify this with this command:

```
$ systemctl cat httpd.service | grep -F ExecReload
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful
```

To stop the Apache HTTP Server:

```
sudo systemctl stop httpd.service
```

which, behind the scenes, sends a `SIGWINCH` signal to the `httpd` process.

This can be verified with this command:

```
$ systemctl cat httpd.service \
  | grep -E --before-context=1 'ExecStop|KillSignal'
# Send SIGWINCH for graceful stop
KillSignal=SIGWINCH
```

The `systemd.service` [3] manual says that in this situation, where the `ExecStop` option is not specified, "the process is terminated by sending the signal specified in `KillSignal`."

Why `SIGWINCH`? Because, per https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50669 , Apache uses the `SIGWINCH` signal as a 'graceful shutdown' trigger.

Another command you may find useful to explore service options is the `show` command combined with `-p, --property` options, like this:

```
$ systemctl show httpd.service -p ExecStart -p ExecReload -p ExecStop -p KillSignal
```

[1] https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!httpd.git/c7/SOURCES!httpd-2.4.3-apctl-systemd.patch
[2] https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html
[3] https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Answer (score 1):

As with other Linux distributions that use systemd, you can manage httpd with `systemctl`. In particular:

```
systemctl reload httpd
```

will cause httpd to reload its configuration files and restart its workers with the new configuration, exactly as `graceful` did.

Comment: then how to graceful stop apache?